# Refresh BufferedImage

Tags: java, refresh, draw, bufferedimage, mouse-listeners

I wanted to create a simple paint brush in JFrame. To do it, I have created an **BufferedImage** and when the mouse is dragged, I've just redrawn it with set to the image changes.

The problem is that if I drag mouse too fast not all points are drawn.
It looks like dotted line.

And here is my code where I update the image:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) 
{   
    int x = evt.getX();
    int y = evt.getY();

    if(eraser == false)   
        this.Dice(x, y);
    else
        this.Eraser(x, y);

    g = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, positionX, positionY, null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

In **Dice** and **Eraser** methods I make changes to the **image** (I set pixels).
I don't really know how to repair it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics`, override `paintComponent` and paint the image there and then call `repaint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to Swing "buffering" the mouseDragged-event (i.e. if the mouse is moved more than one pixel per interrupt, it will only get called once). 
You could try storing the latest reported mouse position, and instead of calling `this.Dice()/this.Eraser()` once for the pixel, call it for everything in between the starting(last) position, and the position of the current mouse event.